# How to reject an answer if previous answer and current answer is equal

Tags: java, comparison

I'm currently working on a random number guessing game and i want the logic to be like this:

if i answered, for example, a correct answer "12", how can i make the program reject the answer if i entered 12(a previous answer)?

here's the code i've made:

```
public void cmpans()
    {
        Object arr[]=set.toArray();
        boolean success=false;
        boolean boo=false;
        String txget;
        txget=gametext.getText();
        String pars;
        int ans;
        pars=gametext.getText();
        ans=Integer.parseInt(pars);

        int cans[]=new int[10];

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {

            if(ans==arr[i])
            {
                ck[i].setSelected(true);
                gametext.setText("");
                lblives.setText("life: "+life);
                lbcons.setText("cons: "+cons);
                userscore=userscore+10;
                lbscore.setText("Score: "+userscore);
                success=true;
            }
            else
            {
                boo=true;
                gametext.setText("");
                gametext.requestFocus(true);
            }
            arr[i]=null;
        }

        gametext.setText("");
        gametext.requestFocus(true);
        if(success==true)
        {
            cons++;
            if(cons==3)
            {
                userscore=userscore+20;
                lbscore.setText("Score: "+userscore);
                lbachieve.setText("You're a GOOD GUESSER!");
                lbcons.setText("cons: "+cons);
            }
            else if(cons==5)
            {   
                userscore=userscore+50;     
                lbscore.setText("Score: "+userscore);
                lbachieve.setText("You're an AMAZING GUESSER!!");
                lbcons.setText("cons: "+cons);  
            }
        }
        else if(boo==true)
        {
            cons=0;
            life--;
            lblives.setText("life: "+life);
            lbcons.setText("cons: "+cons);
        }

    }
```

thanks in advance for all who'll help!

Comment: it's always a good idea to provide the code you're currently using or have tried

Answer (score 2):

Use a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), check if the provided answer is inside it by adding the element with **add**, and checking if the result is true or false.

For more info on Java collections, check this nice [cheat sheet](http://initbinder.com/bunker/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/collections.png).

Comment: It would make more sense to use a `Set` since the `add` will return `false` if the element already exists in the collection.

Comment: very true, I was updating the answer to using hashset when I read your answer :-P.